# Why does aria-hidden="true" get removed when using sanitizing callback wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this snippet.

```
function html_sanitize_text( $input ) {
    return wp_kses_post( force_balance_tags( $input ) );
}
```

I am using this to sanitze `html` in the Wordpress customizer.

The html inside this text field is `<i class="fa fa-laptop" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

when saving my changes in the customizer - then refresh - then go back to this field inside the customizer, Wordpress strips/removes  `aria-hidden="true"`.

Any idea why? and how to work around this?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason you are not using wp_kses? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses you can pass through what to ignore that way and it wont strip it your aria-hidden code then

Comment: No reason at all... wasn't sure what was the best way to display html and sanitize it. @SimonPollard

Comment: Give it a go, you have more control with that function, give me a shout if you need any more help :) A lot of wp functions are variations of others in an attempt to make life easier but sometimes its nice to have some control.

Comment: Thanks @SimonPollard for helping me out.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to the [wp core pag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses_post#Description) about `wp_kses_post`, it mentions that it only allows "post content with allowed HTML tags".

Upon further investigation, if you look at the [kses.php file](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/kses.php#L0), the section about allowable tags and attributes does not include `aria-hidden`, so I assume it gets cleaned out of the html by the function.

Also in regard to sanitizing your input, is simply using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` (in reference to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)) not sufficient?

Comment: Thanks dude. Your information helped me come up with a solution for my problem.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my problem with this function. Please correct or edit if it can be better.

```
function html_sanitize_text($input) {

    $filtered = wp_kses($unfiltered, $allowed_html, $allowed_protocols);

    $allowed_html = array(
        'aria-hidden' => array(),
        'i' => array(
            'class' => array(),
            'aria-hidden' => array()
        ),
    );

    return $input;
}
```

This doesn't strip out `aria-hidden="true"` from my input field in the Customizer when saving my changes.

Posted this in case someone in the future has this issue when using the font awesome library in Wordpress.